# find a basis of $\ker L$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have the linear transformation:

$L:\mathbb{R^4} \rightarrow \mathbb{M_2}(\mathbb{R}), \, (a,b,c,d) \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
   a & c-b \\
   b-c & a+d 
\end{pmatrix}$

I would like to find a basis of $\ker L$ and of $\operatorname{Im} L$, how is it possible to do it ?

Thank you

Comment: $\ker(L)$ is just the set of all quadruples which are mapped to the zero matrix, what relations must they satisfy? You can then easily write this as a linear span.
For $\text{Im}(L)$ try to show that the top left and bottom right entry can be chosen arbitrarily and the other two satisfy a sign-reversing relation. You can then easily write the set of all such matrices

Comment: for ker L then a=0, c-b=0 b-c=0 and a+d= 0 ? I do not manage to do it according that we have a matrix with variables instead of number

Comment: Yes. Now write every element satisfying this as the linear span of some (1-dim) basis?

Answer (score 0):

We have $ (a,b,c,d) \in Kef(L)$ then $$ \begin{bmatrix} a & c-b \\
b-c & a+d \end{bmatrix}  = 0$$
Then $ a=0$, $b=- c$ , $ a=d=0$, so that $(a,b,c,d) = (0, b, -b, 0 )=b ( 0,1,-1,0) $. So $\{   ( 0,1,-1,0) $} is aa system of generator  for  $Kef(L)$ , as this vector is non zero , then it is linearly indepenedent ,and hence it form basis for $Kef(L)$ .

On the other hand, any $4 \times 4$ matrix in $Im(L) $ has the form  $$ \begin{bmatrix} a & c-b \\
b-c & a+d \end{bmatrix}  $$  so it is to write 
$$ a \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  + b \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}  + c \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + d \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  $$
$$ = aE_1+bE_2+cE_3+dE_4$$
Thus $ \{  E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4\}$ is a system of generator of $Im(L)$. clearly $  E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4$ are linearly independent, hence they form a basis for  $Im(L )$ .

Comment: May be the answer is late , but it would helps others when check the post for the same concept .